# How to display ui-router state on whole page?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using ui-router for state handling. This works fine, but now I have to create page 404 and would like to display it on the whole page and not inside the page as other pages.

```
app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider',
    function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {

        $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!').html5Mode({
            enabled: true,
            requireBase: false
        });

        $stateProvider
        .state('stateIndex', {
                    url: '/',
                    templateUrl: '/templates/list.html',
                    controller: 'dashListController'     
        })
        .state('stateList', {
                    url: '/list',
                    templateUrl: '/templates/list.html',
                    controller: 'dashListController'
        }).state('stateDashboard', {
                    url: '/dashboard/:id',
                    templateUrl: '/templates/dashboard.html',
                    controller: 'dashboardController'
        })
        .state('stateWidgetsList', {
                    url: '/widgetsList',
                    templateUrl: '/templates/widgetsList.html',
                    controller: 'widgetsListController'
        })
        .state('404', {
            url: '/404',
            templateUrl: '/templates/404.html'
        });
}]);
```

and on my index.html I have

```
<div ui-view></div>
```

where I display all the pages, outside of this I have logo, menu, etc.. which I would like to hide while displaying 404 page.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Personally I would redesign the index.html, and bring the outer template (logo, menu, etc), into it's own template and state. Then you can sit child states below it in the ui-router hierarchy. For example:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('app', {
                abstract: true,
                url: '',
                templateUrl: '/templates/appcontainer.html'
    })
    .state('app.stateIndex', {
                url: '/',
                templateUrl: '/templates/list.html',
                controller: 'dashListController'     
    })
    .state('404', {
        url: '/404',
        templateUrl: '/templates/404.html'
    });
```

Then you just need to put your logos/menus, etc inside `appcontainer.html`, and then just have a single `<div ui-view></div>` inside your index.html. Also if you do it this way, don't forget to add the child `ui-view` inside `appcontainer.html`.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a root parent state that will contain your layout stuff (logo, menu, etc) and have the 404 live outside of that.

**routes**

```
$stateProvider
  .state('root', {
    abstract: true, // makes this state not directly accessible
    templateUrl: 'root.html'
  })
  .state('root.stateIndex', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: '/templates/list.html',
    controller: 'dashListController'
  })
  // ...
  .state('404', {
    url: '/404',
    templateUrl: '/templates/404.html'
  });
```

**root.html**

```
<nav><!-- menu stuff --></nav>
<ui-view></ui-view>
<footer></footer>
```